# Windows clock is running slow

Tags: windows-10, clock

My windows system clock is running slow. I've sat with a stopwatch and checked, each second it counts takes about 1.5 seconds. It synchronises normally every hour or so with windows time server and catches up.

The PC otherwise runs completely fine, and is used for gaming and reasonably heavy statistics work with no issues.

The bios clock is running at the correct speed. I've rebooted, updated Windows, repaired the installation, and replaced my CMOS battery. None of this has helped.

Why is this happening? Can it be fixed?

Comment: I would first doublecheck if the replacement battery is supplying 3.0V. These things should be good for a decade after manufacturing, but sometimes they're not (or they're older than you think). I would also clean the contacts on the battery holder (and the battery itself as well). How old is the main board?

Comment: You might find that re-registering the time service as shown in [FIX: System Time/Clock Running Faster Than Normal](https://appuals.com/system-timeclock-running-faster-than-normal/) helps - it mentions the same BIOS clock correct/Windows clock wrong problem that you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, this worked for me!

> You might find that re-registering the time service as shown in FIX:
> System Time/Clock Running Faster Than Normal helps - it mentions the
> same BIOS clock correct/Windows clock wrong problem that you describe.
> –  Andrew Morton Aug 10 at 16:01

Answer (score 0):

You can try the suggestion in this article:
https://www.techbout.com/fix-slow-incorrect-windows-computer-clock-14287/
Basically you can change the clock server and check if the Windows time service is running.

Regards,
V

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The asker mentions *"It synchronises normally every hour or so with windows time server and catches up."* - that sounds like both the Windows time service is running and whichever time server was set is successfully being polled. I would suspect a hardware issue rather than synchronisation.